# pandas How to drop the whole row if any specific columns contains a specific values?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataFrame like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPiBk.png)

I wonder how to drop the whole row if any specific columns contain a specific value?

For example, If columns Q1, Q2 or Q3 contain zero, delete the whole row. But if columns Q4 or Q5 contain zero, do not delete the row.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPiBk.png)

Comment: Welcome on SO please, read two points [why-not-upload-images-of-code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question) and [how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) to filter with [`eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) and [`any`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) along axis 1, and logical NOT operator `~`:

```
df.loc[~df[['Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3']].eq(0).any(1)]
```

#### Example

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5,5), columns=['Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3', 'Q4', 'Q5'])

df.loc[1,'Q1'] = 0
df.loc[4, 'Q2'] = 0
df.loc[3, 'Q5'] = 0
```

[out]

```
         Q1        Q2        Q3        Q4        Q5
0  1.764052  0.400157  0.978738  2.240893  1.867558
1  0.000000  0.950088 -0.151357 -0.103219  0.410599
2  0.144044  1.454274  0.761038  0.121675  0.443863
3  0.333674  1.494079 -0.205158  0.313068  0.000000
4 -2.552990  0.000000  0.864436 -0.742165  2.269755
```

---

```
# Should drop rows 1 and 4, but leave row 3

df.loc[~df[['Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3']].eq(0).any(1)]
```

[out]

```
         Q1        Q2        Q3        Q4        Q5
0  1.764052  0.400157  0.978738  2.240893  1.867558
2  0.144044  1.454274  0.761038  0.121675  0.443863
3  0.333674  1.494079 -0.205158  0.313068  0.000000
```

Answer (score 0):

We can consider this a conditional filtering problem. We want to only keep rows, where the columns Q1, Q2 and Q3 are non-zero:

```
df_new = df[(df["Q1"] != 0) & (df["Q2"] != 0) & (df["Q3"] != 0)]
```

This `df_new` now only contains rows that you want.